# how to generate missing weekids in python dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataset given below with `weekids` indexed:

```
product_name    serial_number     date           sum
"A"             "12"              "202001"   150        
"A"             "12"              "202002"   350
"A"             "12"              "202004"   550
"A"             "12"              "202005"   1500
```

Here, assume that my current weekid is `"202007"`, and I need to convert those missing weekids with zeros for a given current weekids `"202007"` given below:

```
product_name    serial_number     date           sum
"A"             "12"              "202001"   150        
"A"             "12"              "202002"   350
"A"             "12"              "202003"   0
"A"             "12"              "202004"   550
"A"             "12"              "202005"   1500
"A"             "12"              "202006"   0
"A"             "12"              "202007"   0
```

Can you please help me how to convert first dataset into second one efficiently in python using with pandas dataframes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so generate the data

```
data = {'product_name' : ['a','a','a','a'],
        'serial_number': [12,12,12,12],
        'date': [202001,202002,202004,202005],
        'Sum': [150,350,550,1500]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

this gives

```
  product_name  serial_number    date   Sum
0            a             12  202001   150
1            a             12  202002   350
2            a             12  202004   550
3            a             12  202005  1500
```

then do the work, this is making the big assumption that you want to do this by product_name as well as week number

```
outdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
s=range(202001,202008)
for name, subdf in df.groupby('product_name'):
    thisdf=subdf.set_index(['serial_number','date']).\
        Sum.unstack().reindex(columns=s,fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
    thisdf.rename(columns={0: "Sum"}, errors="raise",inplace=True)
    thisdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
    thisdf.rename(columns={'index': 'product_name'}, errors="raise",inplace=True)
    thisdf['product_name'] = name
    thisdf = thisdf[['product_name', 'serial_number', 'date', 'Sum']]
    outdf = pd.concat([outdf,thisdf])
    outdf = outdf[['product_name', 'serial_number', 'date', 'Sum']]

outdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
outdf = outdf[['product_name', 'serial_number', 'date', 'Sum']]
```

and this yields

```
    product_name    serial_number   date    Sum
0   a               12              202001  150
1   a               12              202002  350
2   a               12              202003  0
3   a               12              202004  550
4   a               12              202005  1500
5   a               12              202006  0
6   a               12              202007  0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = [{'product_name': 'A', 'serial_number': '12', 'date': '202001', 'sum': 150},
 {'product_name': 'A', 'serial_number': '12', 'date': '202002', 'sum': 350},
 {'product_name': 'A', 'serial_number': '12', 'date': '202004', 'sum': 550},
 {'product_name': 'A', 'serial_number': '12', 'date': '202005', 'sum': 1500}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

create a dataframe with date to add and append to the origin dataframe.

```py
# first find out which date to add -> {'202006', '202007', '202003'}
date_list = [str(date) for date in range(202001, 202008)]
date_to_add = set(date_list) - set(df['date'].values)

# create a dataframe with date = list(date_to_add), sum = 0, and append to the origin df
dfn = pd.DataFrame({'date':list(date_to_add),'sum':0})
df_result = df.append(dfn).sort_values('date').fillna(method='ffill')
```

result:

```
print(df_result)

  product_name serial_number    date   sum
0            A            12  202001   150
1            A            12  202002   350
2            A            12  202003     0
2            A            12  202004   550
3            A            12  202005  1500
0            A            12  202006     0
1            A            12  202007     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to expose the missing combinations; at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'product_name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
 'serial_number': [12, 12, 12, 12],
 'date': [202001, 202002, 202004, 202005],
 'sum': [150, 350, 550, 1500]})

df

  product_name  serial_number   date    sum
0   A           12              202001  150
1   A           12              202002  350
2   A           12              202004  550
3   A           12              202005  1500


# install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git

import janitor
(
    df.complete(columns = [{"date": lambda x: np.arange(202001, 202008)}], 
                fill_value={"sum": 0})
      .ffill()
)

product_name    serial_number   date    sum
0   A   12.0    202001  150.0
1   A   12.0    202002  350.0
2   A   12.0    202003  0.0
3   A   12.0    202004  550.0
4   A   12.0    202005  1500.0
5   A   12.0    202006  0.0
6   A   12.0    202007  0.0
```

With Pandas only, you can create a series that has all the values from `202001` to `202008` and merge to existing dataframe:

```
complete_array = pd.Series(np.arange(202001, 202008), name="date")
complete_array

0    202001
1    202002
2    202003
3    202004
4    202005
5    202006
6    202007
Name: date, dtype: int64

(
    df.merge(complete_array, how="outer", on="date")
    .sort_values("date") # you can add ignore_index=True to reset the index
    .fillna({"sum": 0})
    .ffill()
)

    product_name    serial_number   date    sum
0          A            12.0     202001     150.0
1          A            12.0     202002     350.0
4          A            12.0     202003     0.0
2          A            12.0     202004     550.0
3          A            12.0     202005     1500.0
5          A            12.0     202006     0.0
6          A            12.0     202007     0.0
```